# What is the basis for it being called the Tree of Immortality?

Tags: life

I have been reading through the different religions and noticed that the tree of immortality is consistent among Chinese mythology and Islam.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_life

What is the basis for Islam viewing it as a Tree of Immortality?

Other Abrahamic religions simply call it the Tree of Life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was called so by Satan to deceive Adam, his lure was that by eating it he would remain in paradise forever.

> فوسوس إليه الشيطان قال يا آدم هل أدلك على شجرة الخلد وملك لا يبلى
>
> Then Satan whispered to him; he said, "O Adam, shall I direct you to the tree of eternity and possession that will not deteriorate?"
>
> <sup>— [Quran 20:120](http://quran.com/20/120)</sup>

> وقال ما نهاكما ربكما عن هذه الشجرة إلا أن تكونا ملكين أو تكونا من الخالدين
>
> (Satan) said, "Your Lord did not forbid you this tree except that you become angels or become of the immortal."
>
> <sup>— [Quran 7:20](http://quran.com/7/20)</sup>

---

```
Other Abrahamic religions simply call it the Tree of Life.
```

It is the same thing, as 'life' there means 'eternal life':

> And the Lord God said, Behold, the man is become as one of us, to know
> good and evil: and now, lest he put forth his hand, and take also of
> the tree of life, and eat, and live for ever
>
> <sup>— [Genesis 3:22](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+3:22&version=KJV)</sup>